# What are defines in STL mean?

Tags: c++, libstdc++

Recently i was viewing std::array header file, and i've found some wierd defines, such as _GLIBCXX20_CONSTEXPR or _GLIBCXX17_CONSTEXPR etc. Why are they needed?

Comment: That question can be answered only by whoever wrote those defines, or by reading the rest of the header file and seeing what they do.

Comment: _"...the identifiers that begin with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter are reserved; [for the implementation] ..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers

Comment: I've read file, in which they defined, it was something like "#if __cplusplus > some numbers define _GLIBCXX17_CONSTEXPR constexpr" so it does not make any sense for me. My first thought was that it used only for knowing when this header was written. So that is why i asked it here

Comment: Careful with the lessons you learn from the Standard Library headers. They are written by folks intimately know their compiler and the platforms with which the headers will be used and will be performing all manner of unsavory acts to make the library run as efficiently as possible within compiler and platform constraints. They know when they can indulge in a bit of undefined behaviour which you may not be able to take for granted.

Answer (score 5):

`_GLIBCXX20_CONSTEXPR` expands to `constexpr` when using C++20 or newer, and to nothing otherwise.

`_GLIBCXX17_CONSTEXPR` is similar, but for C++17.

Comment: Crisp - Worth mentioning: [C++20 feature testing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test)

Answer (score 4):

These macros are empty if a compiler does not enable support of C++17 or C++20 respectively. The different macros are required since C++20 adds more constexpr API after C++17.

The similar macro _GLIBCXX14_CONSTEXPR exists. C++17 adds more constexpr API after C++14.

There is no constexpr API prior C++11.

Example [**std::array<T,N>::at**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at), C++ Containers library std::array

```
reference at( size_type pos ); (until C++17)
constexpr reference at( size_type pos ); (since C++17)
```

That looks in the header file like

```
_GLIBCXX17_CONSTEXPR reference at( size_type pos );
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly i looked for, thank you!